# Convert to binned events in time in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have a list with times at which an event happened. I would like to convert this in Python to a list with binned times (for example 0 - 2 seconds, 2 - 4 seconds etc.) and a list with how many events happened between those times.

For example if I have the following times at which an event happened:

```
event_times = [1,2,4,7,8,9]
```

And the following time array:

```
time = [0,2,4,6,8,10]
```

I expect the following output:

```
count = [0,2,1,0,2,1]
```

which tells me there are 2 events between 0 and 2 seconds, 1 event between 2 and 4 seconds, etc (including the upper bound). The first zero is kind of redundant, because it will always be zero.

Right now I solved this with two for-loops, which works, but is terribly slow:

```
count = numpy.zeros(len(time))
for i in range(1,len(time)):
    for j in range(len(event_times)):
        if event_times[j] > time[i-1] and event_times[j] <= time[i]:
            count[i] = count[i] + 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the expected output precisely (and pythonic-ly), use `np.digitize` and `np.bincount`

```
count = np.bincount(np.digitize(event_times, time, right = 1))

count
Out[619]: array([0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1], dtype=int32)
```

`np.histogram` won't work because it uses left-limits, unless you fudge the values.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using numpy's `histogram` function.  It accepts a list or array or numbers to be counted, and you can pass in the bin divisions.  It defaults to including the lower bound of the bin range, not the upper.  But that is easy to work around.

```
import numpy as np
event_times = [1,2,4,7,8,9]
time = [0,2,4,6,8,10]

counts, bins = np.histogram(event_times, bins=time)
counts

#returns:
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2])
```

To include the upper bound, you can simply add a small offset to `time`.

```
counts, bins = np.histogram(event_times, bins=np.array(time)+1e-10)
counts

#returns:
array([2, 1, 0, 2, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Daniel F's answer is probably what you want, since you're already using numpy. If for some reason you're looking to implement it yourself and the time array represents a continuous span, which it seems so judging by your `if` statement, you can reduce the run-time to `O(n)` (for `n = len(event_times)`):

```
count = numpy.zeros(len(time))
for j in event_times:
    count[int(numpy.ceil(j / 2))] += 1
```

If the `time` array doesn't start at 0 simply subtract the appropriate offset.